# Show Image rad studio xe8 (c++ builder)

Tags: c++

For my new project I have decided to program in c++ rad studio xe8 (until now I have programmed in c++ builder 6.0), I was convinced that the changes, being an evolution of builder, would not be many, but wanting to show a background image in the form : fail.
When compiling it does not give me any error, but the image is not shown (neither in the master view, nor in the desktop view.....)

**Code:**

```
AnsiString PathFich = ExtractFilePath(Application->Name);
Fondo = new TImage(this);
Fondo->Bitmap->LoadFromFile(PathFich+"Img\\Fondo.png");
```

Comment: Have you checked if the file is loaded correctly? What is the value of `PatchFich`, and will it create a nice and *valid* absolute path when concatenating `"Img\\Fondo.png"`? If you don't get an absolute path, is the relative path correct compared to the process [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)?

Comment: Thanks for answering..The path is correct.. If I address a path that does not exist, when compiling it shows me the error. As this does not indicate an error, it executes the Form correctly but without showing the image, even if I add an onclick event in the timage it works correctly for me.

Comment: If you *debug* and check the value of `PathFich` (or just print it out somehow), what does it say?